Does anyone know this movie/tv show with aliens?
I think it was this tv episode where there was a "deformed" man who looked different and was super sad so he agreed to trade places with an alien knowing he could never come back and in the end when he was going to the door he passes the alien going to earth and it was a beautiful woman and she was like, "does everyone on your planet look like you?" And he walks through the door and it was full of people who looked like him. It may have been The Twilight Zone but I don't think so.

Hi. Can you approximate the year\decade? Was it in B&W or color? Was it American? Where did you see it?

Possibly an epsiode of Night Gallery, The Different Ones.
Based on The Eye of the Beholder from The Twilight Zone.
From Wikipedia's description of The Eye of the Beholder:

The episode was written by Rod Serling, who recycled the theme for a
  later teleplay "The Different Ones" for his later series Night
  Gallery. This one takes place in a futuristic world where a disfigured
  hermit teenage boy is sent on a NASA rocket to a planet where the
  inhabitants are revealed to look like him. During the transfer he
  meets a handsome (by human standards) alien youth, who is going to
  Earth due to his own disfigurement.

I can't find a video clip, but here's an image:


And I also think this particular episode had a remake in the "new" 2000s Twilight Zone series. Although in that one, things went a little differently in a plastic surgery direction. But the premise was the same.
